# Teradata exporting Time results in the Number format

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Teradata is exporting Time results in the Number format instead of the Time format. For example: 12:33 is exporting to 1233. However, while displaying the results in TeraData SQL assistant, the format is ok.

Comment: This time column is probably a Float or Int (one of the dbc tables?), you need to cast it to a char, e.g. `trim(timecol)`

Comment: How are you "exporting" the data?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution: If you extract the data using ODBC connection then it won't create trouble like you have to connect and select the server every time.
However if you connect using TeraData's default connection name then it will give you this issue.

Comment: ODBC actually has problems with TIME while .NET doesn't (and newer releases of SQL Assistant also allow storing the password for .NET). As I wrote in my comment you probably don't have a TIME, check the data type.